# tr -d to remove an exact string of characters from a string

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, tr

I am trying to make `tr -d` remove a string of characters from an existing string, without it removing characters everywhere else.

For example, I want `tr` to remove `: OK` from the end of every string in `foo.txt`.

Contents of `foo.txt`:

```
BROKEN BONES: OK
Kefen Odvora: OK
BOOKS_FOR_MUM: OK
E: OK Amded: OK
```

This is the command I run:

```
cat foo.txt | tr -d ": OK$"
```

I want it to output this:

```
BROKEN BONES
Kefen Odvora
BOOKS_FOR_MUM
E: OK Amded
```

But instead I get this, which I don't want:

```
BRENBNES
efendvora
BS_FR_MUM
EAmded
```

How can I fix this?

Mac OS X Yosemite, bash 3.2.57(1)-release

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using the wrong tool. You want `sed`, not `tr`:

```
cat foo.txt | sed 's/: OK$//'
```

or preferably

```
sed 's/: OK$//' foo.txt
```

when your input really is just a file, not a more complicated command.

---

`tr -d` removes *all* occurrences of *any* character found in the argument to `-d`; it does not treat it as a regular expression to match and remove. Specifically, you are removing all occurrences of `:`, , `O`, `K`, and `$` from each line.

Comment: IMHO sir, no need to use `cat` as `sed` could read Input_file itself.

Comment: Yeah, I left that as a placeholder from the original question, in case the input was the output of a more complicated command. `sed 's/: OK$//' foo.txt` is sufficient if the input really is just a file.

Comment: Works wonderfully, thank you! And yes, I will only be using this with plain text files. Now, if I were to use this with a complicated command, what would I need to use then?

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to help here.

```
awk '{sub(/: OK$/,"")} 1'  Input_file
```